# Is the Sun losing mass and pushing the Earth further away?

Tags: astrophysics, earth, sun, solar-system, solar-wind

With the sun radiating so much energy every millisecond can nuclear fusion keep up with that pace? And if it can’t keep up isn’t the sun losing energy every second and therefor losing mass? Which leads to a smaller curvature of space time around it and therefor pushing the earth further away.

And if this is true, isn’t this a huge problem? Or are the effects so small that it won’t be a problem until millions of years?

Comment: Nuclear fusion is keeping up the pace. Yes, the sun is losing mass. It won't be a problem ever for the sun, which will not evaporate away.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71652/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The sun loses ~$10^{9}$ kg/s but has ~$10^{30}$ kg so it will take over ~$10^{21}$ s to lose it all or something well over 30 trillion years.