# A confusion between geocentric and heliocentric model

Tags: reference-frames, orbital-motion, inertial-frames, earth, solar-system

As per Ptolemy, he proposed firstly geocentric model and that model if one see with aspects of relativity he would find true. Here is an example how

Suppose you are in a train which is moving and you are sitting in train. A man at platform is waving you and he is steady at his position. Then you would probably see man going backwards if train is moving forwards.

Question arises from this in one's mind that how absolute motion can be observed in a moving frame.

If you apply this logic to Ptolemy model,
You would probably conclude that neither earth is perfectly centre nor sun and earth is stationary(relative to sun) and sun is moving.
Then if you are on earth which is itself moving, let's assume heliocentric is true which everyone believes even me, then how we can conclude somehow that sun must be stationary(relative to earth).
If someone here argues even me that we have gone to outer space and viewed sun is stationary and earth is moving along it, but here comes another possibility too that maybe the end of our galaxy is moving so again similar thing happen that how absolute motion can be detect from a moving frame. So to have some proper results between heliocentric and geocentric some proper research must be done to solve such questions.

If any of you have some answers please write, I will be pleased if you do so.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking. Speed is relative, there is no absolute rest frame. Acceleration (including rotation) is not relative. The Sun is moving relative to the galaxy, the galaxy is rotating, and moving relative to neighbouring galaxies. Et cetera.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we say that the earth moves around the sun?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10933/)

Comment: No john it's not a duplicate just checkout arguments I have done

Comment: Also [What made us think that Earth moves around the Sun?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55444/)

Comment: Yep maybe I was not knowing about it